# How i can use the same column sidebar in multiple pages in R Flexdashboard?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I need inputs to be global for multiple pages

[the dashboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOfEm.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is by using

```html
Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================
```

instead of:

```html
Column {.sidebar}
=====================================
```